# How to check if first dropdown is selected live time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all I need if first is not selected disable second, if selected enable

**Here is code:**

```js
function checker() {
  if ($('#car option:selected').val() === '') {
    $('#car-model').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('#car-model').prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
checker();
```

```css
select{
  width: 100px;  
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='car'>
  <option></option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
<select id='car-model'>
  <option></option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a change event listener on the car select and check the selected option.

I have added also `$("#car-model").val($("#car-model option:first").val());` to reset the second select value

**Updated the post to use self-invoked function to execute on load**

```js
$("#car").change(function(){

checker();

});

var checker =  (function checker1() {

  if ($('#car option:selected').text() == '') {
    $('#car-model').prop('disabled', true);
    $("#car-model").val($("#car-model option:first").val());
  } else {
    $('#car-model').prop('disabled', false);
  }
  
  return checker1;

})();
```

```css
select{
  width: 100px;  
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id='car'>
  <option></option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>

<select id='car-model'>
  <option></option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If the select is disabled it does not need to have its value reset

Comment: The script is not very readable, redundant function invocation in the event handler and no caching of the objects.

Comment: @mplungjan I think its better for the user experience to see an empty select when disabled.. As for the code, there surely is a better approach and your answer might be cleaner, but my answer was based on the SO code provided..

Comment: except yours is nolonger invoked on page load like original. Also when I see an if and a boolean it bothers me

Comment: Updated the post to use self-invoked function to execute on load

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that uses the test for value as a boolean and also executes on load of the page in case they are returning from somewhere

```js
$(function() {
  $("#car").on("change", function() { 
    var dis = $(this).val() === '';
    $('#car-model').prop('disabled', dis);
  }).change(); // execute it onload too
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='car'>
  <option></option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>

<select id='car-model'>
  <option></option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Alternative, resetting the second select if needed

```js
$(function() {
  $("#car").on("change", function() { 
    var dis = this.value === '', $model = $('#car-model');
    $model.prop('disabled', dis);
    if (dis) $model.val(""); // reset second select
  }).change(); // execute it onload too
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='car'>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id='car-model'>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like following.

```js
$('#car').change(function() {
    $('#car-model').prop('disabled', this.value == '');
}).change(); //execute on page load
```

```css
select{
  width: 100px;  
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='car'>
  <option></option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>

<select id='car-model'>
  <option></option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah I was battling whether or not to oneline it using `this.value`, but decided against it for noob readability's sake

Answer (score 1):

Just change your jquery function to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#car-model').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#car').change(function(){
      if ($('#car option:selected').val() != ''){
      $('#car-model').prop('disabled', false);
  }
  else{
     $('#car-model').prop('disabled', true);   
  }
  });
});
```

And, it will work.Here the working plunker for you with your code and just the change in jquery function: http://plnkr.co/edit/aZJonNNhadrxlqg0LwzK?p=preview

Comment: yeap, code optimisation is left. Thanks for the suggestion, however i wanted to go with his original source code.

Comment: But you have `$('#car-model').prop('disabled', true);` twice. What if the select is NOT on the first option when loading?

Comment: $('#car').change(function() {
    $('#car-model').prop('disabled', this.value == '');
}).change(); //execute on page load  is still the optimal. Upvoted you for your answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling the selectbox by jquery, you can add a disabled attribute to the second selectbox :)

```js
$("#car").change(function(){

checker();

});

function checker() {

  if ($('#car option:selected').text() == '') {
    $('#car-model').prop('disabled', true);
    $("#car-model").val($("#car-model option:first").val());
  } else {
    $('#car-model').prop('disabled', false);
  }

}
```

```css
select{
  width: 100px;  
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id='car'>
  <option></option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>

<select id='car-model' disabled=true>
  <option></option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is already hammered to death. No new code in your suggestion - also you ARE using jQuery - the code is identical to earlier posted code